# Pytorch optimizer returns empty

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I already check relevant questions but can not figure out what is wrong with my code. I build a cnn and add residual value but, it returns

> "ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list"

In below you can see some of my code

```
 def _init_(self):
        super()._init_()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 10, 3, 1, 1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(10, 5, 3, 1, 1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(5, 10, 3, 1, 1)
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(10, 10, 3, 1, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(40960, 15)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.15)

    def forward(self, x):

        x = (F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = (F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = (F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        residual = x.clone()
        x = (F.relu(self.conv4(x)))
        x += residual
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = (F.relu(self.conv5(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))

        return x
```

and it returns error in here:

```
net = Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learn_rate, momentum=0.9)
```

thank you for your helps in advance

Comment: init requires double underscores: `__init__()` Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of net.parameters()? optim.SGD() is expecting an ["iterable of parameters..."](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.SGD.html). Try this:

```
net = Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
parameters = list(net.parameters())
optimizer = optim.SGD(parameters, lr=learn_rate, momentum=0.9)
```

Comment: `net.parameters()` returns a generator

Comment: Yes, it does not work but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `Net` class needs to extend [torch.nn.Module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html)

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def forward(self, x):
        ...
```

Comment: Well it already extends but I did not share that part. It still doesn't work, thanks anyway